# IWebElement does not contain a definition for 'Count'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public static void WaitAndSelectAnItem()
{
 WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
 var imageLink = wait.Until(d => 
 {
    var elements = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector(""));
    if (elements.Count > 0)
      return elements[0];
    return null;
  });
  imageLink.Click();
}
```

I am trying to wait for a element to be present on the page, if it is then proceed by clicking it. However I am getting an error with the Count in my IF statement.

Error message: IWebElement does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method Count accepting a first argument of type IWebElement count could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: Use FindElements instead. (s at the end)  Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.CssSelector(""));

Comment: Was going to say, `FindElement` returns a single element, `FindElements` returns multiple ones, but @Morvader got to it first.

Comment: Oo, thank you guys. Sorry I didn't notice that. @Morvader :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed final 's' on FindElement**s**

If you want to retrieve multiple elements you should use `FindElements` instead.

This should work:

```
 var elements = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.CssSelector(""));
 if (elements.Count > 0)
  return elements[0];
 return null;
```